# Autorun .bat file with no admin rights in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, uac, autorun

I want to try to run .bat file just after loading windows 7 system, but the problem is that i have no rights of admin and the UAC is on. Is that possible? Or maybe is it possible to write the program that is opening (not in autorun folder) but opening it depends for instance on a windows clock time?

Comment: Do you want to run the file before the desktop displays or after?

Comment: I want to run it after. Maybe i can put it to registry?

Comment: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run maybe? But it works i think only for me as a user, or to the whole PC?

Comment: i forgot to add that i can also use usb port and cd/dvd but of course autorun is disabled because of the system

Comment: If the UAC is enabled and you do not have admin right you will not be able to edit the registry.

Comment: what is funny i can ;P

Comment: Ok then you can add that as registry setting.  If you add it to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE it will apply to all users.

Comment: the same directory as in current user?

Comment: Yes the same registry key as in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the program in the start folder.  This will run the program everytime that windows start up.

Click start -> All programs -> Startup.  Drag the .bat file into this folder.

Comment: unfortunately because of right i cannot put it to startup folder in start menu ;/